# How can I deep compare objects/arrays in useEffect/React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I just wanted to know that how can I deep compare objects/arrays in useEffect or React Hooks do it already under the hoods? I am trying to make it work too in the same way for the hook version.

In the previous version I was doing like below;

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   const { settings: { config = {} } = {}, pluginData = [] } = this.props
   const { settings: { config: nextConfig = {} } = {}, pluginData: nextPluginData = [] } = nextProps

   if(!_.isEqual(config, nextConfig) && !_.isEqual(pluginData, nextPluginData )){
        //do sth with new props
   }
}
```

For the next version;

```
useEffect(() => {
 // do sth with new props
}, [props.settings.config, props.pluginData])
```

As you see, I was using lodash's isEqual to compare whether it's the same object/array or not. How to do it in hooks? How does React compare when I pass nested objects/arrays to the dependency array of useEffect? Does it do a deep comparison or shallow?

And also;

What should I do whether I am not sure props have settings and config
in the previous version, I was doing like below;

```
const { settings = {} } = nextProps
```

How to do it in the hook version? Should the same approach continue?

PS: `config` is a nested object and `pluginData` is an object array.

//// AFTER ASKING CLARIFICATION FOR THE QUESTION

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
      settings: { config: { data: { enabled: nextEnabled = false } = {} } = {} } = {},
      pluginData: nextPluginData = []
    } = nextProps || {}

    if (nextEnabled) {
      if (nextPluginData[0]) {
        this.setState({ disabled: !nextPluginData[0][nextEnabled] })
      }
    }
  }
```

I working on the rewrite of one of the components that is already written with class cmp. How can I convert this piece of code from class cmp to hook cmp?

Comment: Since they are `props` when they change in the parent component, they should have a new reference and your child component will be re-rendered. There is no need to deep compare them. If however, your reasoning behind this question is to limit the number of rerenders (which it is not said explicitly), you should look into [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: I really know, they get a new reference ever time when parent render, but if you are using lodash's `isEqual` and your object has no functions inside of it (fn that created during render) changed reference doesn't matter. It will compare as expected and gets true when it is. My point is, gets the new value from props if it really changes.

Comment: Perhaps you've not explained clearly enough the use case. Vivere is correct. You don't, or shouldn't, need to do a deep equality as you can just use a deep dependency as you have done, and when *that* value has changed from the previous render, trigger the effect callback. Is the "equality" issue more to do with the array?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can do something like this:

```js
const [config, setConfig] = useState(undefined);
const [pluginData, setPluginData] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
    if(!_.isEqual(config, props.settings.config) && !_.isEqual(pluginData, props.pluginData)) {
        //do sth with new props

        // Update old props to have them actual for the next comparison
        setConfig(props.settings.config);
        setPluginData(props.pluginData);
    }
}, [props.settings.config, props.pluginData])
```

Basically, you can have a state of the old props and then deep compare them.

Comment: Great answer. In your example, there are two comparisons one is obvious isEqual you did, and the second one is in the dependency `[props.settings.config, props.pluginData]` What are the differences between these two comparisons? Isn't it the same? I mean, Doesn't React compare `config` and `pluginData` deeply when we use useEffect with dependency array?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use `use-deep-compare-effect` library, it provides a hook like `useEffects`, but it compares the dependent objects deeply with their previous values.

```
import useDeepCompareEffect from 'use-deep-compare-effect';
...
useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    // The codes that were in the useEffects previously
}, [dependentObject]);
```

Also, here is the link to this library:

https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect